# how to extract and plot the chat from azure devops chartimages api

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-logic-apps, azure-devops-rest-api, azureportal

how to extract and plot the chat from azure devops chartimages api

I am using the below api i azure logic app
GET [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/{team}/_apis/work/iterations/{iterationId}/chartimages/{name}?api-version=6.0-preview.1](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/%7Bteam%7D/_apis/work/iterations/%7BiterationId%7D/chartimages/%7Bname%7D?api-version=6.0-preview.1)

I am also getting an answer with the below fields but how to plot the graph

{
"$content-type": "image/png; api-version=6.0-preview.1",
"$content": "a large string value"
}

Answer (score 0):

> how to extract and plot the chat from azure devops chartimages api

As the log you get shows, the result of the REST API is in `png` format. So, we need to perform simple processing on the obtained results and save the results in `png` format:

The Rest API [Chartimages - Get Iteration Chart Image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/chartimages/get%20iteration%20chart%20image?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0):

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/{team}/_apis/work/iterations/{iterationId}/chartimages/{name}?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

I use the `Burndown` as test chartimages `name`.

Below is my test powershell scripts:

```
$outfile = "D:\TestFolder\Burndown.png"

$connectionToken="Your PAT Here"

$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::  
ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))

$AuditLogURL = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/{team}/_apis/work/{iterationId}/chartimages/Burndown?api-version=6.0-preview.1" 

$AuditInfo = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $AuditLogURL -Headers @{authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -Method Get –OutFile $outfile
```

The test result:

[image]